# Why the simple exponential smoothing returns the same forecast for different observations

Tags: time-series, statsmodels

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import SimpleExpSmoothing

x = [1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 100, 10, 80, 270, 10, 50,  590]

model = SimpleExpSmoothing(x)
curFit = model.fit()
print(curFit.forecast(5))
```

I think I should get predictions for next 5 time steps
and I got array([598.12025545, 598.12025545, 598.12025545, 598.12025545,
       598.12025545]). All values from curFit.forecast are the same no matter how I am changing x.  Why? What is the sense of returning the same values?